# Why is @first always false in my handlebars #each loop?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember.Handlebars, I'm trying to set up a Bootstrap carousel to showcase a selection of issues from my data store.

I want to add the `active` class on the first item of my carousel, but **it sounds like my** `{{if @first}}` **test is never evaluated true**.

- My `app/templates/issues-list.hbs` is :

  ```
  <div id="showcase-issues" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          {{#each model.issues as |issue|}}

              {{#if @first}}
              <div class="active item">
                  {{#issue-item issue=issue}}{{body}}{{/issue-item}}
              </div>
              {{else}}
              <div class="item">
                  {{#issue-item issue=issue}}{{body}}{{/issue-item}}
              </div>
              {{/if}}

          {{/each}}
      </div>
      {{!-- Nav buttons, etc. ... --}}
  </div>
  ```
- My `app/routes/issues-list.js` is simply :

  ```
  model: function() {

      var issues = this.get('store').filter('issue', {
          filters: { "state" : "visible" }
      }, function(item) {
          return (item.get('state') === "visible") ;
      }).then( function(results) {
          return results ;
      }) ;

      return Ember.RSVP.hash({issues: issues}) ;
  }
  ```

Did anyone already face this problem ?

**Is there a proper way to handle** `DS.FilteredRecordArray`**s in a** `{{#each ...}}` **helper ?**

---

I'm working with :

- Ember 1.13.2
- Ember-data 1.13.5
- Bootstrap 3.3.5

---

Thanks a lot for any given hand !

Comment: Is the active class set on other elements at one point or is it always on the first one?

Comment: Bootstrap will toggle it at runtime, yes. But the issue that I want to display first will always be... the first, effectively. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@index` and `@first` isn't available in htmlbars. You can however:

```
{{#each model.issues as |issue index|}}
  <div class="item {{unless index 'active'}}">
    {{#issue-item issue=issue}}{{body}}{{/issue-item}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

See: http://jsbin.com/zupezap/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: ALMOST : Thanks a lot ! Your version gives the compilation error : `A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block.` but after a few tries I fixed it ! [Working JSBin here.](http://jsbin.com/zupezap/2/edit?html,css,js,output) Have a nice day, enjoy your coding !

Comment: @Brou Ah, didn't realize, thanks. That looks cleaner too. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Marked solved but : can you please adjust the JSBin link ? Thanks again !

Comment: This is brilliant! Nice one